# For media streaming, WiFi connection requirement on Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, media-server

I will connect Ethernet cable from my modem+router to Raspberry Pi. And I will connect external HDDs etc to RPi via a powered USB hub. Now if I want to stream media from the connected HDD, does the RPi needs a WiFi? Because I will be connecting to this network over WiFi only, on my iPad or my laptop.

IOW, does my raspberry pi needs a WiFi if I want to stream media present in HDD which is connected to Pi over USB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As you will connect to your Raspberry pi via the router anyway, it will work with the cable connection.

Comment: So lets say, I connect my Pi to router on ethernet and it has IP address 197.168.2.56 and I start running DLNA server on some port, say 5555. So on my iPhone, in the media player app I have to enter the IP and Port address of RPi and it should work right?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: I just checked, I have VLC media player installed in my iPhone and it does not have option to enter any address. It automatically searches for the DLNA server. I don't know whether search is done only over WiFi, but it is not able to detect my DLNA server.

Comment: Is your iPhone connected to the router (via WiFi)?

Comment: Yes, it is connected to router over WiFi.

Comment: Now, I'm not an iPhone expert, but if I where you, I'd download some kind of terminal software to the phone and try to ping the pi from it. Does that work?

Comment: seems there was some issue with my modem. Reset and reconfigured and its working properly now!